# Join in search results

Tags: mysql, sql, search, join

This is query I have at the moment:

```
SELECT
    `groups`.`id`,
    `groups`.`name`,
    `groups`.`description`,
    `groups`.`members`,
    `groups`.`image`,
FROM
    `groups`
WHERE
    `groups`.`name` LIKE '%a%'
    OR
    `groups`.`description` LIKE '%b%'
```

All works as expected, but I need one additional thing to select. Problem is that its stored in another table and I'm not so good with joins. Here is 2nd table structure:

`group_members`

- `group_id`,
- `user_id`,
- `status`;

I need to select specified user status for group! Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advice!

**Edit:**

I need to display all groups and current user status in each of those groups.

**Edit #2:**

Lets say that `user_id` is set to `33`. He types `aa` as group name and in results he see all groups that have `aa` in its name. In addition, in results are his status in each group.

```
ID    Name    Description    Status

2     aa2     foobar         3
2     aa1     foobar         1
4     aa3     foobar      
6     aa3     foobar      
5     aa3     foobar         2
```

**Edit #3:**

Here is almost what I need...

```
SELECT `groups`.`id`, `groups`.`name`, `groups`.`description`, `groups`.`members`, `groups`.`image`, `group_members`.`status`
FROM `groups`
LEFT JOIN `group_members`
    ON (`group_members`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`)
WHERE `group_members`.`user_id` = '33'
    AND `groups`.`name` LIKE '%%'
    OR `groups`.`description` LIKE '%%'
```

Only problem, I does not select groups where I'm not member. Interesting why... I did use 'left outer' join.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I don't understand what you need to select well enough to write it...

Comment: Looks like you're mixing things up. Each group only has one description and one image, but many members. What is it that you want to display? *All* the members, with all the per-group data repeated on each row?

Comment: Having 'group_members`.`user_id` = '33' condition in the where clause is going to filter the results which do not have this user_id. If you want all groups where user_id = 33 is a member or not a member then remove this condition from the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you , its very easy to add a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), like :

```
SELECT
    `groups`.`id`,
    `groups`.`name`,
    `groups`.`description`,
    `groups`.`members`,
    `groups`.`image`,
FROM
    `groups`
LEFT JOIN group_members
ON `groups`.`id` =  group_members.group_id
WHERE
    `groups`.`name` LIKE '%a%'
    OR
    `groups`.`description` LIKE '%b%'
   AND group_members.status  = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
INNER JOIN group_members
ON group_members.group_id = groups.id
```

after

```
FROM
    `groups`
```

and then add

```
group_members.status
```

to your select

Answer (score 0):

If you want groups irrespective of whether they have any group_member or not then use a LEFT OUTER JOIN as below. If you want only those groups that have group_member(s) then change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT
        `groups`.`id`,
        `groups`.`name`,
        `groups`.`description`,
        `groups`.`members`,
        `groups`.`image`,
         group_members.status
    FROM
        `groups`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN group_members
    ON group_members.group_id = groups.group_id
    WHERE
        `groups`.`name` LIKE '%a%'
        OR
        `groups`.`description` LIKE '%b%'
    AND status = 'something'
```